# Построение графиков функций WinRT c# xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, canvas, функции, winrt

Пишу курсач на тему "Написание программы для построения графиков функций". Выбрал технологию WinRT как основную фишку. Программа должны быть максимально простой и адаптивной для разных устройств. Я сделал весь интерфейс и дизайн, но с самим построением графиков проблемы. Не знаю как графически их построить. Думаю с помощью Canvas вывести массив точек, будет не красиво, но зато будет, но и тут у меня проблемы.

Как вывести кучу точек на Canvas? Или может подскажете что-нибудь более подходящее для такой задачи нежели "Canvas"?

Буду ооочень благодарен!

Answer (score -1):

Допилил с помощью polyline, коряво получилось, но работает и масштабируется хорошо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, опишите решение проблемы более детально, чтобы пользователям было легче понять ваш ответ. Для редактирования ответа, нажмите [Edit]. Так же можете ознакомиться с советами о том, [как написать хороший ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). - [Из очереди проверок](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/149651)